# Stacking two characters vertically in a table with no space between them

Tags: css, html-table, vertical-alignment, cellspacing

This should be really simple, but I can't figure it out.  So: how do I get these two characters to merge up in a table?

```
〳   1st row, U+3033 VERTICAL KANA REPEAT MARK UPPER HALF
〵   2nd row, U+3035 VERTICAL KANA REPEAT MARK LOWER HALF
```

Those are used in the vertical writing of Japanese, and they're supposed to look like a big version of U+3031 VERTICAL KANA REPEAT MARK  〱 when combined.  But simply setting border-spacing, padding, collapse etc isn't enough, since there's still space above and below the chars themselves.  Failed attempt:

```
<table style='border-collapse:collapse'>
  <tr><td>〳</td></tr>
  <tr><td>〵</td></tr>
</table>
```

So how do I squeeze the juice out of the text?  I suppose the ideal answer would be to use 'real' vertical writing capabilities in a browser, but as far as I can tell [this](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-writing-modes/) is still a utopian draft.

Comment: "Utopian Draft"  I like that: +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to also use border-spacing: 0;. That along with padding:0; will help. They should match, however, depending on the padding the actual font character has, you might have to use a div, and set the height/width so that it clips.

You might be better off with Div's, if you are simply trying to display the character.

http://www.gateshosting.com/test/slash.html

```
<div>
 <div style='border:0;padding:0;font-family:tahoma;font-size:15px;height:14px;'>/</div>
 <div style='border:0;padding:0;font-family:tahoma;font-size:15px;height:14px;''>\</div>
</div>
```

Surely there has to be a solution if you search for it on a Japanese blog or something.

Answer (score 0):

If you can wrap them in a `span`, then this works http://jsfiddle.net/zdqvM/5/ and the shift seems to be correct even at higher font-size: http://jsfiddle.net/zdqvM/6/.

Comment: Neither of those quite line up on my browser =/

Comment: Oh well, they looked great on FF 8!

Comment: FF8 here as well.  May be fonts or something, I'm on OS X.

Comment: Ahh. I'm on Win7. Must be font's. Which probably proves the point that no matter what you choose, its not going to look right on somebody's computer.